# Add a member to a group with DirectoryServices

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, directoryservices

I create a group in my Active Directory with DirectoryServices.

```
Imports System.DirectoryServices
Imports ActiveDs

Module Module1

Sub Main()

    Dim dom As New DirectoryEntry()

    Dim ou As DirectoryEntry = dom.Children.Find("OU=projects")

    Dim group As DirectoryEntry = ou.Children.Add("CN=pracmans", "group")

    group.Properties("Description").Value = "Red Bull"

    group.Properties("groupType").Value = ActiveDs.ADS_GROUP_TYPE_ENUM.ADS_GROUP_TYPE_UNIVERSAL_GROUP Or ADS_GROUP_TYPE_ENUM.ADS_GROUP_TYPE_SECURITY_ENABLED

    group.Properties("samAccountName").Value = "pracmans"

    group.CommitChanges()

End Sub

End Module
```

Source: [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180903(v=VS.90).aspx)

This works perfectly.

Now I want to add an existing User as a member to this group. (as descripted [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180904(v=vs.80).aspx))

So I added

```
group.Properties("member").Add("CN=John Doe,OU=Employee,OU=London,DC=me,DC=intra")
```

If I run the script now it stops at the `CommitChanges()` an tells me that the server isn't able to execute my request.

Do I miss something?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Edit: I made some own progress - it should be the right UserDN now, sadly it didn't change the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself.

My first mistake was the wrong DN of the User I wanted to add.

[Active Directory Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/adexplorer.aspx) is an amazing tool, which helped me to find the right DN.

The second mistake is actually not my fault as the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180904(v=vs.90).aspx) article is wrong. The way they connect to the group doesn't work.

Here you have my code on: "How to add a member to a AD Group using DirectoryServices"

```
Imports System.DirectoryServices


Module Module1

Sub Main()

    Dim dom As New DirectoryEntry()

    Dim ou As DirectoryEntry = dom.Children.Find("OU=projects")

    Dim group As DirectoryEntry = ou.Children.Find("CN=pracmans", "group")

    group.Properties("member").Add("CN=John Doe,OU=employee,OU=London,DC=me,DC=intra")

    group.CommitChanges()

End Sub

End Module
```